# getting Error while IONIC build properties.gradle does not Exist

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, gradle, ionic3, build.gradle

1. i am trying to creating ionic build, but getting error, here is my step.
2. ionic cordova platform remove android
3. ionic cordova platform add android
4. ionic cordova build android

> while i run last command then got below Error.

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
```

- Where:
  Script 'D:\Projects\corporatesolutionmobileapp\platforms\android\cordova-android
  -support-gradle-release\sancial-cordova-android-support-gradle-release.gradle' l
  ine: 11
- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred evaluating script.

  > Could not read script 'D:\Projects\corporatesolutionmobileapp\platforms\androi
  >   d\app\cordova-android-support-gradle-release\properties.gradle' as it does not e
  >   xist.
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug
  option to get more log output.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1s
[ERROR] An error occurred while running subprocess cordova.

```
    cordova build android exited with exit code 1.

    Re-running this command with the --verbose flag may provide more
    information.
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Updating to the most recent version (v2.0.1) of `cordova-android-support-gradle-release` should resolve your issue:

```
ionic cordova platform rm android
ionic cordova plugin rm cordova-android-support-gradle-release
ionic cordova plugin add cordova-android-support-gradle-release@latest 
ionic cordova platform add android
ionic cordova build android
```

Answer (score 46):

I was having a similar problem, running the command 
`ionic capacitor run android` 
I was getting androidmanifest.xml doesn't exist.

It was solved by running the command 
`ionic capacitor update`

Comment: this fixed it for me

Comment: thanks, man ... it helped me in getting the issue fixed.

Answer (score 6):

Updating Capacitor did the trick for me:

```
npx cap update
```

Comment: This is not a question, but an answer.

Answer (score 5):

I was getting this error while only using Capacitor which I thought was strange so I [nuked](https://capacitor.ionicframework.com/docs/android/troubleshooting/#recreating-your-project) the `android` path in my root folder and then `npx cap add android` again and the build worked after that

Answer (score 0):

This issue is mostly faced, when you add/remove a new plugin. So by just running `cordova clean` can resolve that issue.

Inside your CMD/Terminal:

```
C:\<project folder>\cordova clean
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  It is related to M1 chipset of mac.

   % brew uninstall node
   % brew install nodenv 
   % echo 'export PATH=${PATH}:~/.nodenv/shims' >> ~/.zprofile 
   % nodenv install 17.7.2
   % nodenv global 17.7.2

   % npx cap run android
   ✔ Copying web assets from www to android/app/src/main/assets/public in 7.48ms
  ✔ Creating capacitor.config.json in android/app/src/main/assets in 745.25μs
  ✔ copy android in 12.87ms
  ✔ Updating Android plugins in 3.42ms
  [info] Found 3 Capacitor plugins for android:
   @capacitor/camera@1.3.1
   @capacitor/filesystem@1.1.0
   @capacitor/geolocation@1.3.1
  ✔ update android in 32.04ms
  ✔ Running Gradle build in 1.32s
  ✔ Deploying app-debug.apk to emulator-5554 in 1.88s


 ref https://github.com/ionic-team/capacitor/issues/5545
```

Answer (score -2):

Solved:

- Delete the Android Directory from your folder
- Follow the steps mentioned in the ionic capacitor troubleshoot documentation at

https://capacitorjs.com/docs/android/troubleshooting#recreating-your-project